# Pdf is showing raw data in IE ()

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tomcat, pdf

I am trying to load PDF from URL to an object inside HTML div 
below is the code snippet

```
<div id="id" style="position:relative; height:100%; width:100%;">
    <object id="object" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
```

It works fine for small PDF and when I am trying to load large PDF (>10 MB) in IE 9 or 10 Browsers showing raw PDF instead of file like

%PDF-1.4 ........... %%EOF

Please help me on this

Comment: More code will help or JSFIDDLE

Comment: Is this a problem with static PDF files (read off the disk) or dynamic ones that you are generating yourself at request-time?

Comment: The Pdf was dynamic which the html file have the URL from tomcat server and trying to load from java script